# tf_debug does not trigger the filter has_inf_or_nan

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am struggling to get a minimum working example for detecting nans in a tensorflow computation graph going.

I have looked at the MNIST example provided by Google and it works fine. However, I cannot seem to understand why the code below does not work, i.e. if I type

```
run -f has_inf_or_nan
```

into tf_debug, the filter is never triggered.

Here's the code I am using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug

c = tf.zeros((6,1))
o = tf.ones((1,23))

out1 = c/o
out2 = o/c
out3 = tf.log(c)

out4 = out2 + out3

sess = tf.Session()
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
sess.add_tensor_filter('has_inf_or_nan', tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan)

for i in range(10):
    out_np = sess.run([out1, out2, out3, out4])
    print(out_np)
```

Running this code will just print a bunch of nans without ever triggering the filter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't `has_inf_or_nan` a built in filter? I don't get the impression that you need to define it. Try commenting out `sess.add_tensor_filter('has_inf_or_nan', tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan)` and see if it works.

Comment: I'm going off this text in the TF docs: "tfdbg> run -f has_inf_or_nan
NOTE: The preceding command works properly because a tensor filter called has_inf_or_nan has been registered for you when the wrapped session is created." https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger

Comment: Does not work, when I comment out adding the filter I get: ERROR: tensor filter 'has_inf_or_nan' does not exist